# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln(x^2+1)-\ln(x-1)$

Tags: limits, logarithms

How would you solve the following limit? The method I used can be seen below. I'm just not sure if it's   valid. I was thinking perhaps a substitution for $(x-1)$ might also work, but when I followed through with and it there was still an $x$ in the expression.

Evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln(x^2+1)-\ln(x-1).$$

My method:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln(x^2+1)-\ln(x-1)$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{\ln(x-1)}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln(x)+\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\ln(x)+\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln(x)+\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)- \left[{\ln(x)+\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right]$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln(x)+\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)- {\ln(x)-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \ln\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)- {\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$

$$\therefore \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = \infty- 0 = \infty.$$

Comment: You have done something really weird. Note that $\log a - \log b = \log(a/b)$ you have tried to write it as $(\log a)/(\log b)$.

Comment: Simpler: $\ln(x^2+1)>\ln x^2$ and $\ln(x-1)<\ln x$, so expression is greater than $\ln x^2-\ln x=\ln x$ which obviously tends to infinity with $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first new equation is already wrong: The correct identity gives is $$\log (x^2 + 1) - \log (x - 1) = \log \frac{x^2 + 1}{x - 1}.$$

> **Hint** Notice that the numerator satisfies $x^2 + 1 > (x - 1)^2$.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I completely over stepped that. Makes the solution magnitudes easier. Thanks, Travis.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to factor out $x$: $\log (x^2 +1) = 2 \log x + \log (1+ \frac{1}{x^2})$. Then you get a term that diverges and 2 terms that converge to 0.